# Call method as bind expression inside mustache tags and return value

Tags: vue.js, binding, quasar

In the following case, the total value is supposed to be rendered in the avatar.

If I uncomment 'return 7' in the method, the number 7 is rendered in the avatar.

If I uncomment console.log () I get the total value correctly.

However with `return response.data.total [0].total` I can't display the value.

```
<q-avatar v-if="item"> {{ getItemNumber(item) }}  </q-avatar>


methods: {      
    getItemNumber(item){
       // return 7; //OK
        this.$axios.get(`/getnumber/${item.id_parent}`)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.success) {

                //console.log(response.data.total[0].total); // get number 7      
                return response.data.total[0].total; //??

          } else { }
        })
        .catch(error => {         
        });
    }
}
```

codpen: https://codepen.io/ijose/pen/dyoVyLj

codpen simulate mounted(): https://codepen.io/ijose/pen/zYGEGOe

Answer (score 0):

You also need to return your `axios` call from your `getItemNumber` function.

so the `return 7;` will work as it's not in the axios call it will return the value directly. but for returning the value from axios response.

The following code will return the value of the response when `getItemNumber` is invoked

**Try this**.

```
getTotal(car){
         console.log(car.id_car);        

         // return 7; //OK


        return this.$axios.get(`/totalsales/${car.id_car}`)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.success) {   
                return response.data.total[0].total; //?? HERE

          } else { }
        })
        .catch(error => {         
        });
         // -->
      }

function axiosTest() {
  return axios.get(url).then(response => {
    // returning the data here allows the caller to get it through another .then(...)
    return response.data
  })
}

axiosTest().then(data => {
  response.json({ message: 'Request received!', data })
})
```

**Updated**

Just create Mapping dict instead.

```
total_dict:{}
```

Methods

```
getTotal(car){
         console.log(car.id_car);        
           axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/barbier`)
        .then((response) => {
            this.$set(this.total_dict,car.id_car,response.data.id)
        .bind(this)})
        .catch(error => {         
        });

      }
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/XWbezrJ?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you for you help Patel Patrik. I tried your suggestion, but instead of returning the total value '7', it returned the string  [object Promise]

Comment: Or use async and async function

Comment: Thank you Patel Pratick. In this solution, how the getTotal method is called (no longer integrating mustach tags). I tried with async function (and await this.$axios ...), but it always returns a Promise object. One idea was to deal with this Promise to return the correct value in the mustache tags, but I have not been successful so far.